# SIP ALG detector

Tags: wireshark, voip, sip

I am trying to create a detector for SIP ALG. I really just need to know what the BEST method of testing this is so I can write a program to test whether SIP ALG is enabled or disabled.

Thanks

Comment: There is considerable [documentation](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/) for Wireshark.  What have you tried?  Is there any way to get a similar scenario working as you like, and then modifying it for your specific scenario?

Comment: No, I just want to know what it is exactly in a VoIP capture in Wireshark where I can find whether SIP ALG is activated or not.